# Add 2 private subs to 1 worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi how can i add both of these codes to 1 worksheet ?
The code auto copies data from 1 sheet to another
Thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If LCase(Target.Value) = "y" Then
        With Target.EntireRow
            .Copy
        Sheets("sheet9").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlValues
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If LCase(Target.Value) = "b" Then
        With Target.EntireRow
            .Copy
        Sheets("sheet10").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlValues
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot have two subroutines with the same name in one module - event routines are no exception. Just put the code into one routine and use an `ElseIf`-statement to distinguish the cases.

Comment: Or convert your two change events into separate subs and create another `Worksheet_Change` event to just call the correct macro based on some condition. So, 1 worksheet change event and 2 sub

Comment: Or just dynamically assign your sheet variable

Comment: sorry but i have no idea how to do that, still learning excel

Answer (score 1):

Your two subs do essentially the same thing, so you only need one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As string
    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        Select Case LCase(Target.Value) 
            Case "y": ws = "Sheet9"
            Case "b": ws = "Sheet10"
        End select
        If ws <> "" Then
            Thisworkbook.sheets(ws).cells(rows.count,1).end(xlUp).offset(1,0).Entirerow.value = _
              Target.EntireRow.Value
            
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, really appreciate, worked!

Comment: Please click the green check mark to the left instead of commenting. That shows that this question has been answered.